# Unable to install, no screens found

Tags: system-installation

Im trying to get ubuntu 11.04 beta 2 installed. Upon booting from the cd there is a purple screen, "ubuntu" and an activity indicator. This goes on for 30 seconds to a minute and then jumps to a teminal/prompt. I don't know what to do from here?

I have tried "startx" but that results in the following errors:

> (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a
>   usable configuration.
>
> Fatal server error: no screens found

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you MD5 test the ISO you downloaded? Did you burn the CD as slowly as you could? Did you test the CD for defects once first booted to?

Comment: I redownloaded the iso and it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the Activity indicator press Enter and then F6. Arrow down to "nomodeset", then spacebar to mark it and boot.